# Input validation using C

Tags: c, validation, input

I'm writing a program to prompt the user to enter a number between 1 and 5. If the value is greater than 5 or less than 1 I want the program to wait until an appropriate answer is given. This is what I came up with and it's not working. I've tried a few different tips off the net and it still isn't working. Any tips would be great, thanks.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int p1_move;

    do{                         
        printf("1  \n 2 \n 3 \n 4 \n 5\n");
        printf("Player 1, enter the number:\n");
        scanf("%d", &p1_move);
    }while(p1_move >=6 || <=0);         
}
```

Comment: `while(p1_move >=6 || p1_move <=0);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a variable for each test:

```
while(p1_move >=6 || p1_move <=0);
```

You also have potentially undefined behaviour here:

```
scanf("%d", &p1_move);
```

You do not test whether the input was successful.  If the input failed first time around (*eg* EOF or non-integer input), `p1_move` will remain uninitialised.

Answer (score 1):

Your code shouldn't compile.

Change

```
while(p1_move >=6 || <=0);
```

to

```
while(p1_move >=6 || p1_move <=0);
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked. Alternatively, would there be a way to make the while statement say anything that ISN'T 1/2/3/4/5? I thought it was !1!2!3!4!5

Comment: @KThund Not really, `!a` results as `0` for all non-zero `a`, results as `1` for zero. You still need to test them separately like `a != 1 && a !=2 && a != 3` etc.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. I was thinking of making it so if any character or number other then 1,2,3,4or5 is entered it will repeat the same prompt. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: @KThund I'm not saying the logic is wrong. I'm saying the syntax should be like `while (a != 1 && a !=2 && a != 3)`.